# How to keep MongoDB multi tenant PHP SaaS application approach

Tags: php, mongodb

We are developing SaaS based application in PHP using mongoDB as database.

Our approach is 1 database for each user. Inside each database there may be approximate 200K records.

We are targeting 500 users in a 6 months, so there will 500 database on server in a 6 months.

Can any one suggest what number of database should be there on one sever? 
How to manage load on a server?

Comment: We are targeting minimum 5 users per tenant. And we are going to deploy our application on AWS server. What should be our possible infrastructure on AWS server?

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided, is quite difficult to say. We don't know what load  will have the servers, the average document size, how powerfull  will be your hardware, if you will use replication or sharding ...

Anyway you have other options. Check [this document](http://docs.mongohq.com/use-cases/multi-tenant.html), created by MongoLab guys.